# Return oriented programming with arguments using arbitrary EBP

Tags: c, x86, exploit

I've been reading [this article](http://codearcana.com/posts/2013/05/28/introduction-to-return-oriented-programming-rop.html) about "Return oriented programming" and I have a question about the part with "Calling arguments"

What I understand is that we need to have a stack in correct format. Arguments and then return address we don't care about. They set up the stack this way:

```
| 0x8048580 <not_used>             |
| 0x43434343 <fake return address> |
| 0x8048360 <address of system>    |
| 0x42424242 <fake old %ebp>       |
| 0x41414141 ...                   |
|   ... (0x6c bytes of 'A's)       |
|   ... 0x41414141                 |
```

Where address `0x8048360` is address we'll jump to after the corrupted function finishes and address `0x8048580` is an argument.

What I don't understand is how can we have a fake EBP address. My understanding was that the EBP address on stack is popped before returning from the function and then the EBP is used to access arguments and local variables. If we put fake address on the stack, wouldn't the `system` function use this fake EBP address to access it's argument without success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> wouldn't the "system" function use this fake EBP address to access it's argument without success? If we put fake address on the stack, wouldn't the "system" function use this fake EBP address to access it's argument without success?

No. That would happen if you overwrite EBP and then *really return from the function to the caller*. Since you are also overwriting the return address, you never actually return to the caller, and you enter `system` instead. What will happen when returning into `system` will be:

```
0x0804847a <+22>: ...    ; Here %ebp is still valid.
0x0804847f <+27>: leave  ; Same as: mov %ebp, %esp; pop %ebp
0x08048480 <+28>: ret    ;          %ebp becomes invalid, but %esp is still valid.
                   |   
                   v
0x08048360 <+0>:  push   %ebp       ; Push the invalid value.
0x08048361 <+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp  ; Move %esp (valid) into %ebp ==> %ebp is now valid again.
```

That's why the article you reference says "fake EBP", because you don't really care about the value. As long as your function does not really return to the caller, you're fine and your ROP chain will continue without a problem because every function you jump into will have a prologue just like the one above.

You can test this by starting your program under GDB like this:

```
$ gdb ./program

(gdb) break *0x08048480     # address of the 'ret' instruction
(gdb) run <<< "$(python -c 'print "A"*0x6c + "BBBB" + "\x60\x83\x04\x08" + "CCCC" + "\x80\x85\x04\x08"')"
```

Then, when you hit the breakpoint, look where you are with the `disassemble $eip` command and then proceed with `si` (step single instruction) and use `info registers` to look at the values of the registers after each instruction.

Comment: I see. So `pop ebp` happens only if we really return the original caller but because we didn't we still have the original correct value in ebp?

Comment: ah, okay. thanks for clarification. for some reason i thought it was the callee's job to clean the stack before returning control to the caller.

Comment: @fishysushi it is, but after "cleaning" it `%esp` still is valid because `leave` does `mov %ebp,%esp` and `%ebp` had a valid value until that. See my updated example above, that should make things clearer.